# How can I copy a YII project to another server?

Tags: yii, nginx

I have got a YII website and I would like to make a copy from it to another domain on nginx server.

I just tried to copy it, but it doesn't working. It looks like it don't use my htaccess?

I know when I make I new project I have to install it. Is there any copy-er for YII?

Comment: You get some log error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probable reason it is not working is because you have to change the location of the entry script in the index.php for the correct location for the yii main folder.

Try doing this :

1. **Try making a new Yii webapp in that location and check that it
   works.**
2. **Now copy the index.php file from that folder and then put it in your
   main webapp.**

If the site is still giving errors then check if the database connection is consistent and check that the server has proper write access to the main webapp folder.

Hope this helped.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Yii is just made of files and (optionally) a database. Provided you copy both to the new server it will just work. Yii also requires server write permissions on /protected/runtime and /assets.

Make sure you're copying hidden (start with .) files too. You could use git for this and clone it into the new server.

Comment: I have copied everything. It looks like it don't use my htacces. This is it: `http://questionfield.com/fgdfgdfg` It don't load YII it's just a simple 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

It was something with the server. We use webmin ot that server and I hade to rewrite the config of this domain manually, after that it works great.